# Invoking DbSet<Type>.Add() method using reflections, in a child class of DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dynamic, reflection, dbcontext

I've got a DbContext child class that talks to the Database through entity framework. I'm using MVC C#.

I've got n DbSets related to my tables. I want to invoke the Add method for any DbSet.Add(entityObject), in this case **UserAccounts.Add(entityUserAccount)** using reflections or dynamic variable.

I'm doing this because I need to inject DbContect by dependency injection in my controllers.

```
public class DataContext: DbContext
{
     public DbSet<UserAccount> UserAccounts { get; set; }

     public void Insert<TypeEntity>(TypeEntity entity) where TypeEntity : BaseEntity
     {
        var typesToRegister = typeof(DataContext).GetProperties().
                     Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(DbSet<TypeEntity>));

        //This is where the code explodes in face:-)
        //Please let me know how to fix it
        var dbSetItem = typesToRegister.First();
        var methodAdd = dbSetItem.GetType().GetMethod("Add");
        methodAdd.Invoke(this, new TypeEntity[] { entity });
     }
}


//Insert<TypeEntity>(TypeEntity entity) is my service 
//method to invoke the DbSet<T>.Add() method.
```

This is the error I get: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
[image]

Comment: So, what is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 2):

I fixed your code. There were two mistakes:

1. Instead of

> var methodAdd = dbSetItem.GetType().GetMethod("Add");

you should write: (because dbSetItem.GetType() will return propertyType not type of the field what you expected)

> dbSetItem.GetValue(this).GetType().GetMethod("Add");

2. And change this row (because Add method should be invoked that way: db.Items.Add(...) not db.Add(...))

> methodAdd.Invoke(this, new TypeEntity[] { entity> });

to that one:

> methodAdd.Invoke(dbSetItem.GetValue(this), new TypeEntity[] { entity> });

And did you forget to invoke SaveChanges method at the end of your code?

```
    public void Insert<TypeEntity>(TypeEntity entity) where TypeEntity: BaseEntity
    {
        var typesToRegister = typeof(DataContext).GetProperties().
                     Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(DbSet<TypeEntity>));

        var dbSetItem = typesToRegister.First();

        var methodAdd = dbSetItem.GetValue(this).GetType().GetMethod("Add");
        methodAdd.Invoke(dbSetItem.GetValue(this), new TypeEntity[] { entity });
        SaveChanges();
    }
```

Comment: Please elaborate a bit on what has been changed and why. That way we all may learn something.

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach is a bit off.

Since you are already in the DbContext class i'm assuming `this` is the context.

```
var dbSet = this.Set<TypeEntity>();

                dbSet.Add(entity);
```

**Update**

You should change

```
dbsetItem.GetType().GetMethod("Add");
```

to

```
dbsetItem.PropertyType.GetMethod("Add");
```

The `typesToRegister.First()` returns a `PropertyInfo`  so we can't use `GetType` .. instead we use `PropertyType`.

And you'll need this change as well.

**Update 2**

```
var dbSet = this.Set<TypeEntity>(); // an actual instance that can be passed to Invoke

    methodAdd.Invoke(dbSet, new TypeEntity[] { entity });
```

Comment: Yes I know but I would like to use reflection. This is a basic example of what I'm doing, but for the actual problem I need reflections.

Comment: @Luther I've udpated my answer. You won't get nulls with this change.

Comment: I've edited the code as you said but at the line "methodAdd.Invoke(dbsetItem, new TypeEntity[] { entity });" (I've also used object instead of TypeEntry) I get an error: "An exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Object does not match target type."

Comment: @Luther I think I understand the issue now. The typesToRegister.First()  simply provides you with the Type but not an instance of it. You'll need to pass an instance of it to Invoke. i'm modifying my answer again to include this.

Answer (score 0):

`dbSetItem` is of type `PropertyInfo` because you called `GetProperties()`. It does not have an `Add` method which is why you are getting a `null` (`GetMethod` returns `null` if a method can't be found that matches).

```
var dbSetItem = typesToRegister.First().PropertyType;
```

You cannot pass `this` into the first parameter of `Invoke`, it needs to be an object of type `DbSet<TypeEntity>`, also your array should be `object[]` (you can pass something else as it will automatically upconvert).

```
methodAdd.Invoke(dbSetItem, new object[] { entity });
```

Comment: I still getting an error, null ref. exception: "Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: @Luther: Missed that problem, `dbSetItem` is a `PropertyInfo`, you need to call `PropertyType`.